# MVC js script broken on \Home\Index but not on \Home

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I'm using a purchased bootstrap template with some added sliders and other goodies for my MVC web site.

I have changed my bundle config for the js like so:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/js/core.min.js",
                  "~/js/bootstrap.min.js",
                  "~/js/script.js"));
```

And I have changed my bundle config for the css like so:

```
        // This includes the bootstrap for the current template
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/css/style.css"));
```

This takes care of getting the JS and CSS in the correct places.... relative paths and all.  There is however a slight gotcha... within the custom script.js file there is some js that also loads OTHER js files.  It seems that the loading of the js includes is not working when the MVC path changes.   So when the path is \Home things load correctly.   When the path is \Home\Index (same page essentially) the js does not load correctly.

Here is a sample of the js that I think is the problem:

```
var o = $(".swiper-slider");
if (o.length) {
    include('js/jquery.swiper.min.js');
```

In my view itself I'm already handling relative paths for images, etc. like this:

```
        <div data-slide-bg="@Url.Content("~/images/header-4.jpg")"  
             class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="swiper-slide-caption"></div>
        </div>
```

To fix the js includes, I could put a slash in front to force the path back to root...  like this:

```
var o = $(".swiper-slider");
if (o.length) {
    include('/js/jquery.swiper.min.js');
```

HOWEVER, I think that comes with some gotchas...

Any ideas on the best way to handle this?

I'm thinking that the standard bootstrap.js and jquery files handle this well with no issues...

**Update:**

For now I added a slash to the js function that loads script files. (see below)  It works, but I'm still wondering if this is the best way to go about it.

```
function include(scriptUrl) {
    document.write('<script src="' + '/' + scriptUrl + '"></script>');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this can be answered...

For now I added a slash to the js function that loads script files. (see below) It works, but I'm still wondering if this is the best way to go about it.

```
function include(scriptUrl) {
    document.write('<script src="' + '/' + scriptUrl + '"></script>');
}
```